# How to Rewrite this R Code in a Single Function

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, arima

This `R` code searches the exact seed that produces the desired coefficient of a simulated `autoregressive` of order 1 AR(1) time-series data using the `arima.sim()` and `forecast::auto.arima()` functions.

**The Problem that Led to the Searching of Exact Seed for `arima.sim()` Function**

If one uses `arima.sim()` function to simulate an AR(1) time-series data and at the same time want to know the parameter or order of such simulated data, one discovers that the specified parameter `ar` and the `order` of the simulated `AR(1)` is not as specified in the `arima.sim()` function. Take a look at this.

```
set.seed(1)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n=10, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
auto_ar <- forecast::auto.arima(ar1, ic="aicc")
auto_ar

#Series: ar1 
#ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean 

#sigma^2 estimated as 1.008:  log likelihood=-14.23
#AIC=30.46   AICc=30.96   BIC=30.76
```

When the `seed` is set at `1`, (`set.seed(1)`) in the above, order and coefficient of autocorrelation is not `(1, 0, 0)` and `0.8` respectively as it was set in the `arima.sim()` function compare to when one set the seed to 289805 (`set.seed(289805)`) instead of 1 or some other seed.

```
set.seed(289805)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n=10, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
auto_ar <- forecast::auto.arima(ar1, ic="aicc")
auto_ar

#Series: ar1 
#ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean 

#Coefficients:
         #ar1
      #0.8000
#s.e.  0.1458

#sigma^2 estimated as 1.849:  log likelihood=-17.25
#AIC=38.49   AICc=40.21   BIC=39.1
```

**This R code searched for the set of seeds that print the correct parameter**

.

Here is the original function

```
FUN <- function(i) {
  set.seed(i)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n=100, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic="aicc")
  cf <- ar2$coef
  ## case handling
  if (length(cf) == 0) rep(NA, 2)  ## sometimes result is `character(0)` -> NA
  else if (substr(cf[1], 1, 5) %in% "0.800") c(cf, i)  ## hit, that's what we want
  else rep(NA, 2)  ## all other cases -> NA
}

R <- 1e3  ## this would be your 1e5
seedv <- 1:R  ## or use custom seed vector

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)  ## for all cores remove `- 1`
clusterExport(cl, c("FUN"), envir=environment())
clusterEvalQ(cl, suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(forecast)))

res <- `colnames<-`(t(parSapply(cl, seedv, "FUN")), c("cf", "seed"))

stopCluster(cl)
```

**What I Want**

I want to rewrite this `R` code to be in a single function (though it may be in a composite function) such that all I need to do is to run and call it with its arguments.

Here is what I tried

```
FUN1 <- function(n, ar, sd, arr, R, FUN2){
  FUN2 <- function(i, n, ar, sd, arr) {
    set.seed(i)
    ar1 <- arima.sim(n=n, model=list(ar=ar, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=sd)
    ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic="aicc")
    (cf <- ar2$coef)
    if (length(cf) == 0) {
    rep(NA, 2)
    }
    else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|intercept"), names(cf))) &  ## using `grepl`
             substr(cf["ar1"], 1, 5) %in% "arr") { 
      c(cf, seed=i)
    }
    else {
      rep(NA, 2)
    }
  }

  seedv <- 1:R

  library(parallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
  clusterExport(cl, c("FUN2"), envir=environment())
  clusterEvalQ(cl, suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(forecast)))

  res <- parLapply(cl, seedv, "FUN2")

  res1 <- res[!sapply(res, anyNA)]  ## filter out NAs

  stopCluster(cl)
}
FUN1(n = 10, ar = 0.8, sd = 1, arr = 0.800, R = 1000, FUN2 = FUN2)
```

1. `n` is the sample size.
2. `ar` is the $\phi$ value.
3. `sd` is the value of standard deviation.
4. `arr` is the value of $\phi$ sort for.
5. `R` is maximum number of seed searched starting from 1.

Comment: this question seems way to broad for this forum. It is not clear at all what you are asking and I doubt that anyone here is going to refactor your code for you. I'd suggest asking **one** specific question at a time, with as little data, code and text as strictly necessary for the question. P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I only take time to explain what brought about the `R code` and what it does (which I think is necessary) before I ask that I want it rewritten ad a single function so one can call the function with its arguments.